# How to download data from multiple folders over https using python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to download files from each folder from 
    `https://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/gfs-avn-hi/201705/`. From each folder I would only need the `0000_000.grb2` files with the last 3 numbers increasing by 12 up to 384. For example, the first file would be `0000_000,grb2` -> `0000_012.grb2` -> etc. After, the program would close and move on to the next folder. I'm still very new to python and programming in general.  This is what I have at the moment. It's a little messy. Would like to get this to work, so I don't have to manually download the data:

```
import urllib

core = 'https://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/gfs-avn-hi/201704/'

year = 2017
month = 05
day = 0
forecast_hour = 0

for i in range (0,31):
    day_fixed = str(day).zfill(2)
    day += 1

for i in range (0,384):
    forecast_hour_fixed = str(forecast_hour).zfill(3)
    forecast_hour += 12



urllib.urlretrieve(core + "/" + year + month + day_fixed + "/" + year + month + day_fixed + "gfs_3_201705" + day_fixed + "_0000_" + forecast_hour_fixed +".grb2", "gfs_3_201705" + day_fixed + "_0000_" + forecast_hour_fixed + ".grb2")
```

Comment: does your script do anything, what does it *not* do?

Comment: I get a type error in line 20 (last line) about not being able to concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: that's because you need to convert everything to strings first, to fix the error, before that line 20 (last line) put `year = str(year)` and `month = str(month)`